# Passing Entity to Annotation Processing class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I need to create a custom annotation. The role of the annotation will be to encrypt

annotated fields calling services.  As the annotated field use other field values in the

entity is it possible to pass the Entity along with the annotated field.

My Hibernate Entity class goes with below format.

```
Class A{

private String field1;
 @CustomEncryptServiceCall
private String field2;

private String field3;
}
```

How to pass the Class A to the annotation processing class.

Comment: And how do you "process" that annotation and introduce the encryption?

Comment: One method to do this would be to use `spring-aop` to create a pointcut at your repository layer where you inspect passed-in values to the repository for your annotation (using normal reflection) and insert the encrypted value into the field.